# $T*T$ Notation and proof

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

Let $T:H\to H$ be compact where $H$ is a Hilbert space and let $T^*$ be the adjoint operator of $T$. Prove that $T^*T$ is compact and self adjoint and that the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ are nonnegative. Find a compact self adjoint operator $S:H\to H$ such that $S^2=T^*T$

What will be a good approach for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a lot of context missing from the question, perhaps it is $T^* \circ T$, where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$?  That is easily seen to be self-adjoint and with positive eigenvalues: Since $(AB)^*=B^* A^*$ and $A^{**}=A$, we have that $(T^*T)=T^*T^{**}=T^*T$.  Further, since if $T*Tx=\lambda x$ and $x\neq 0$, then $$\lambda = \langle T^*Tx,x \rangle/ \langle x,x \rangle =\langle Tx,Tx \rangle/\langle x,x \rangle,$$ which is the quotient of two non-negative quantities, with non-zero denominator.

Finding the square root also isn't so bad.  Since the operator is self-adjoint, the spectral theorem gives an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, and we already have that the eigenvalues are non-negative, and thus have real square roots.  Define $Sx$ on an eigenvector $T^*Tx=\lambda x$ by $Sx=\sqrt{\lambda}x$.  Verify that this is compact and self-adjoint.

It's been too long since I've taken functional analysis to recall the relevant facts about compactness, but hopefully this is enough that you can finish things off (by showing $T^*T$ and $S$ are compact).

Comment: @havakok The question itself may not have more to offer, but the place you found it might.  For example, the fact that $H$ is probably a Hilbert space.The question either came from a book (in which case information about the book and the chapter it was in could be relevant) or it came from a homework sheet, in which case information on the class and what you were covering could be relevant.  My answer made several assumptions about things that were not stated explicitly.

Comment: @havakok just because most Hilbert spaces are denoted by $H$ does not mean that most $H$s are used to denote Hilbert spaces. Just as $i,j$ are common indexing variables, they are also both used for $\sqrt{-1}$. Clearly communicating mathematics requires understanding what assumptions you are making and making them explicit. Small technical conditions can make big differences, and you cannot just assume that others will also assume the same unstated assumptions as you.

Comment: @havakok For you to have even been asking the question you asked, there had to have been a reason why you thought convolution was even an option. Perhaps you were dealing with $L^2(X)$ and were defining operators via integration?  And in a question involving adjoints, you didn't even consider that the star could be taking the adjoint.  If I don't assume there was context to explain your confusion, context to suggest that my answer isn't the only reasonable one, then I am left making unflattering assumptions about you. Do you "get" it?